# Freeing Go Structs of C Objects

Tags: go, cgo

When allocating individual objects via the `C.malloc` based calls, we must free the new items as the Go garbage collector is unaware of them.

EG:

```
s := C.CString(l)
defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(s))
```

However when we create a slice of C objects, do we need to free them?

EG:

`b := make([]C.uchar, C.int(40))`

I was trying to use something like `defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(&b[0]))` however that produces `free(): invalid pointer` and an abort signal.

I see three possible answers:

1. The Go garbage collector is aware of objects created via the `make` call, and so `b` will be garbage collected by the Go runtime.
2. The Go garbage collector is aware of the slice, created via the `make` call, but not the `C.uchar`s contained within the slice. Therefore we need to walk through the the slice, and free each item
3. I am calling the freeing of the slice `b` incorrectly.

Which, if any, of my conclusions is correct? Otherwise what is actually happening?

Comment: You call `free` if you call a C `alloc` function. You didn’t `malloc` anything, therefor you don’t call `free`